# Java request.getParameterMap() apostrophe not being recognised

Tags: java, getparameter

I am trying to obtain URL parameters via `request.getParameterMap()` and I found apostrophe is not getting decoded & is passed as space.

sampleURL : `xyz.com/somename?Marke=Sch%C3%B6ffel%7CLevi%27s`

Here : `Levi%27s` is encoded format of `Levi's`

But when I check parameterMap I get `Levi s`  instead of `Levi's`

What can be cause of this problem ? How do I resolve it ?

Comment: @karthikeyan<br/>
I still have the problem <br/>
URL provided [http://localhost:8080/xyz/ajax/?Marke=Sch%C3%B6ffel%7CLevi%27s]<br/>
Code used to retrieve<br/>
`Map<String, String[]> mapParams = (Map<String, String[]>) httpRequest.getParameterMap();`
<br/>
when I am tried printing the map. I got the below output<br/>
<br/>
Marke<br/>
Schöffel|Levi s<br/>

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and it is working perfectly without any problem, it prints the value with the apostrophe

Comment: <br/> I still have the problem <br/> URL provided [localhost:8080/xyz/ajax/?Marke=Sch%C3%B6ffel%7CLevi%27s]<br/…; Code used to retrieve<br/> Map<String, String[]> mapParams = (Map<String, String[]>) httpRequest.getParameterMap(); <br/> when I am tried printing the map. I got the below output<br/> <br/> Marke<br/> Schöffel|Levi s<br/>

Comment: can you provide me the method that prints the Map contents